# spark-submit option --files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, typesafe-config

I'm trying to load file with configuration, through --files.

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --files tables.conf
```

Then i saw out from

```
SparkFiles.getRootDirectory()
SparkFiles.get("tables.conf")
```

it's normal path.

But when i initialize config, and want using it

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(newjava.io.File(SparkFiles.get("tables.conf")))
conf.getConfig("custom-context")
```

I catch exception "No configuration setting found for key"

Spark version 2.1.0

tables.conf :

```
  custom-context {
    history-type {
      ods=true
    }
  }
```

Can you help me pls?

Comment: can you try --conf "spark.yarn.dist.files=fairscheduler.xml" instead of --files

Comment: thx, but it's not working for me

Comment: Can you add your conf file to your resources folder and try a ConfigFactory.load()

Comment: That works for me. But is there any reason you are trying to give your conf to spark?

Comment: Yes, when i'm putting conf into resource, all works.
But me need, that conf was out package.

Comment: sparkContext.addFile( ... )